# Why do we call Turing reductions many-one reductions?

Tags: computational-complexity

Why do we call Turing reductions many-one reductions? I looked the origin of many-one notation on Google but found nothing.

Comment: A Turing reduction is something _different_ from a many-one reduction. (Or rather, every many-one reduction is also a Turing reduction, but not all Turing reductions are many-one reductions).

Comment: The comment by @HenningMakholm is correct. Let me add that many-one reductions were so named to distinguish them from the even more restrictive class of one-one reductions (which are, not surprisingly, defined just like many-one reductions with the added requirement that the reducing function be one-to-one).